BerHu custom loss function for XGBoost
I would like a loss function that penalizes outliers like the squared loss, while treating small errors less sharply, like the absolute loss. It seems that I am looking for a Huber loss function, but in reverse, the so-called BerHu (providing the paper in which I first saw it used, you can find it in the section 3.2. Loss Function):
$$\mathrm{BerHu}_{\delta}(x)=\begin{cases} |x|, \text{ if } x\le \delta \\ \frac{x^2 + \delta^2}{2\delta}, \text{ if } x> \delta \end{cases}$$
I would like to implement this as a custom loss for an XGBoost . For this implementation, if I am not mistaken, you need to provide the gradient and hessian for the loss. However, BerHu is not twice-differentiable, since it contains the absolute value term. 
I assume that it is for this reason that XGBoost does not even have an implementation for the Huber loss, instead using the Pseudo-Huber loss. 
Essentially I have 2 questions:

What is the best way to try and implement the BerHu loss function for XGBoost? Perhaps I am wrong and there is a way to implement it exactly as is.
In case it is not possible, how would the analogue for a "Pseudo-BerHu" look like? I do not really understand how the Pseudo-Huber loss approximates the Huber loss, so I am struggling to come up with the analogue.

Would appreciate any suggestions on this matter. If there already exists another function that serves the same purpose, which is twice-differentiable, then I would also love to know about it

Looking at the pseudo-Huber loss, given by (to use R code):
pseudo_huber <- function(x, delta) delta^2 * (sqrt(1+(x/delta)^2) -1)

you can see how that gets the quadratic behavior near 0 and linear away from zero:
curve(pseudo_huber(x, 1), -5, 5, lwd=3)
curve(abs(x), -5, 5, add=TRUE, col="blue", lty=2, lwd=2)
curve(x^2, -5, 5, add=TRUE, col="red", lty=2, lwd=2)


Now, one idea is to just use pseudo-Huber with a really small delta to have something well-behaved and more or less linear near 0 (except for really, really close to zero, where it's more quadratic), and to add a to-the-power-4 term in the square root. E.g. like this:
pseudo_berhu <- function(x, delta, eta) (sqrt(1+(x/delta)^2 + (x/eta)^4) -1)

That (in black) certainly behaves sort of linearly near 0 (linear curve shown in blue) and quadratic (shown in red) away from it:
curve(pseudo_berhu(x, 0.1, 1), lwd=4, -20, 20, ylab="f(x)")
curve(x^2, -20, 20, add=TRUE, col="red", lty=2, lwd=3)
curve(abs(x)*10, -20, 20, add=TRUE, col="blue", lty=2, lwd=3)


Now, you'd just need to a factor to make it match the BerHu function you want.
I'm sure one can approach this differently.
Especially the second derivative gets a little messy, but exists and is not constant.

Just to be clear, are you suggesting that I can get by with something similar to the Pseudo-Huber, except modifying it to: $\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{x}{\delta}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{x}{\eta}\right)^4}-1$? And is there a way to try and make it so that I can choose with these parameters where on the x-axis the 'split' occurs? I tried playing around with this formula in Desmos and one way to align this function with $|x|$ and not $10|x|$, like you show, would be dividing by $\eta^2$ and  increasing $\eta$, but then the growth is no longer quadratic

Yes, that's what I'm suggesting. You will not necessarily align it perfectly with something, but more important is what happens on the log-scale (ignoring what becomes additive constant there).
